# RandomForestClassifier Get Top N Predictions and Respective Probabilities

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a Random Forest model `model` and have been able to get its top 3 predictions for each entry using

`predictions = model.classes_[numpy.argsort(model.predict_proba(params_only))[:, :-3 - 1:-1]]`

However, I also want a similar list of the probability NUMBERS that go along with each prediction. The above code only outputs the labels but I also need the probability numbers.

The end goal is to get a list of the top1, top2, and top3 predictions as well as top1prob, top2prob, and top3prob lists so that I can feed it into a pandas dataframe. I have done the first part with

```
prediction1 = [preds[0] for preds in predictions]
prediction2 = [preds[1] for preds in predictions]
prediction3 = [preds[2] for preds in predictions]
```

If I wasnt clear enough and/or you have any questions, please ask them! Thank you!

**NOTE:** A current solution I have is

```
guesses = model.predict_proba(df[PARAM_LIST])
probabilities = [sorted(probas, reverse=True)[:num_preds] for probas in guesses]
```

but I am not 100% sure if this is accurately giving me what I want or if there is a better strategy.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
probs = model.predict_proba(params_only)
predictions = model.classes_[np.argsort(probs)[:, :-3 - 1:-1]]
assert len(probs) == len(predictions)
prediction1 = [preds[0] for preds in predictions]
prediction2 = [preds[1] for preds in predictions]
prediction3 = [preds[2] for preds in predictions]
top1prob = [ probs[i][prediction1[i]] for i in range(len(predictions))]
top2prob = [ probs[i][prediction2[i]] for i in range(len(predictions))] 
top3prob = [ probs[i][prediction3[i]] for i in range(len(predictions))]
```

I tried to keep it similar to your code. It can be done in fewer lines.

From your answer,

```
guesses = model.predict_proba(df[PARAM_LIST])
probabilities = [sorted(probas, reverse=True)[:num_preds] for probas in guesses]
```

This will also work. Because for every entry, numpy.argsort() is sorting labels in descending order, same with sorted(probas, reverse=True)